# rkhunter and unattended-upgrades

Tags: unattended-upgrades, rkhunter

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 system running with `rkhunter` installed. I keep getting warnings in the `rkhunter.log` after `unattended-upgrades` has upgraded the system.

The solution to this would be running `rkhunter --propupd` after every automatic upgrade.

[I found this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RKhunter) which mentions `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90rkhunter`, however, this file doesn't exist on my system.

How can I make sure `rkhunter --propupd` is being executed after `unattended-upgrades` are done?

Comment: You might as well not use `rkhunter` if you're just going to blindly update its signatures at regular intervals.

Comment: @eleventyone it is simply not feasible to investigate the rkhunter logs on hundreds of servers every day. It is expected that `apt` changes signatures. I don't need warnings for something I'm aware that's happening.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90rkhunter` [ships as part of](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fetc%2Fapt%2Fapt.conf.d%2F90rkhunter) the `rkhunter` package, so it must have been removed (and the package will not put it back because it is configuration data). You can download the package and extract its files with `dpkg-deb` to get a clean copy and see what you're missing.